# React Hooks Inputs inside the List

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Good day,

I'm trying to create a form inside the list using react hooks. So far, I'm struggling since I'm only familiar how to make state changes on single state.

```
import React from "react"

export function TestApp () {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    function submitData(){
    // TODO
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input onChange={e=>setInput(e.target.value)} value={value} />
            <button type="button" onClick={submitData}>Submit</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

My sample scenario is like: there is a list of data from web api where I need to iterate in a list. Inside that list, there's an input where user can type or update the data. Something like this below, but it doesn't work properly.

```
import React from "react"

export function TestApp () {
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
         axios.get(`api/customers`).then(response => {
            setCustomers(response.data)
            // suppose the result will be something like:
            // [{id:1, name: "James", {id: 2, name: "Josh"}]
         ).catch(error=>console.log(error));
    }, [])

    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);

    function submitData(){
    // TODO
        console.log(inputs)
        // something like the result will be if the user just added "updated" after the name inside the input list 
        [{id:1, name: "James updated", {id: 2, name: "Josh updated"}]
    }

    function handleOnChange(e, data){
        setInputs(...inputs, {
            id: data.id, 
            name: data.name
        })
    }

    return (
        <> 
           {customers.map((data)=> (
                <input onChange={e=>handleOnChange(e, data)} value={data.name} />
           ))};
            <button type="button" onClick={submitData}>Submit</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

What I want to do is, when the user types inside the selected row, then it mutate changes/updates inside the array. Because the data inside the `inputs` is where I can use to make changes/updates in the backend.

Thank you and I hope somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When mapping, take the current index of the item being iterated over and pass it to a function. In the function, slice the array before and after that index, and at the index itself, replace the `name` property:

```
const changeName = (i, newName) => {
  setCustomers([
    ...customers.slice(0, i),
    { ...customers[i], name: newName },
    ...customers.slice(i + 1)
  ]);
};
// ...
 {customers.map((item, i)=> (
      <input onChange={e => changeName(i, e.currentTarget.value)} value={item.name} />
 ))};
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you! this is actually what I'm looking for!